# What level editor is Phil Fish using in Indie Game: The Movie?

Tags: tools, level-design

[image: Indie Game:The Movie]

Does anyone know what program Phil Fish is using to edit models of levels? Or is it it something he built himself? I'm new to game development and was looking for something to design levels with besides my notebook.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*"Bedard and Fish created their own editor for Fez, called the Fezzer"* ([Source](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/03/06/one-reason-fez-has-taken-five-years-to-make-has-already-won-awa/))

If you need a simple 2D tile editor, [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) is a choice that works for me. There are many others available, some tile-based and some not. A couple more examples are [Ogmo](http://www.ogmoeditor.com/) and [Gleed2D](https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D). Note that all they do is create data - you still need some code in your game to make sense of the data, which may or may not be already written and available.